# Can't have transparent background in OpenGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, transparency, glsurfaceview

I am trying to overlay a SurfaceView with a GLSurfaceView using OpenGL ES 2.0, so I need to set a transparent background in the GLSurfaceView.

After looking for solutions on the internet, I have found that this code normally do the job...

In the SurfaceView:

```
mGlSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
mGlSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
mGlSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
mGlSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
mGlSurfaceView.requestRender();
```

And in the renderer:

```
GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
```

The glSurfaceView overlay the other views, but it is still opaque. I have tried anything I variant of these calls plus some others that have solved the problem for other people, but it doesn't work for me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

IIRC you need to configure the activity as transparent. See:

[How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)